# Making python requests in git pre-commit

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

So in my `pre-commit` I want to run python `requests` to test whether certain urls are valid before committing.

The problem I am having is the `requests` library is not installed.

**Error**

```
- hook id: pre-commit-py
- exit code: 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hooks/pre-commit.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I have tried setting up a virtual env with `pipenv shell` and installing `requests` there, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to the `pre-commit` environment.

I also tried using a different repo in `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/psf/requests.git
  hooks:
    - id: pre-commit-py
      name: pre-commit-py
      entry: python hooks/pre-commit.py
      language: python
      pass_filenames: false
```

---

Code to reproduce

**hooks/pre-commit.py**

```
import os
import sys
import requests
try:
    get = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    if get.status_code == 200:
       print('good')
except Exception as e:
       sys.exit(1)
```

**.pre-commit-config.yaml**

```
repos:
- repo: local
# - repo: https://github.com/psf/requests.git
  hooks:
    - id: pre-commit-py
      name: pre-commit-py
      entry: python hooks/pre-commit.py
      language: python
      pass_filenames: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start by saying your premise is likely a very bad idea -- making requests to arbitrary urls is bound to be very slow to the point where your contributors will be frustrated with such a hook and turn it off.  you'd do better to sequester such a thing to a *test* rather than a pre-commit hook.

that said, it is possible and easy to do what you want within pre-commit -- but you've missed the "how do I install dependencies" part of [local hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks)

notably you'll use `additional_dependencies` to bring in the third party requirement:

```yaml
        additional_dependencies: [requests]
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Thank you for making the suggestion of using a `test` instead of a pre-commit hook which is much better for the scenario.